# How to keep button aligned on desktop horizontal always unless on a mobile phone

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok on my bigger monitor my button instead of horizontal there are three in line then the fourth way down below. I would like to make it so that on desktop the button are all horizontal unless you are on a phone then it stacks vertically. Is this possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Metro-M.svg/2000px-Metro-M.svg.png">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
<title>morgan</title>
<style>
html {
  background: URL("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lYQ3vQHE3Mo/VrVKGwg8pqI/AAAAAAAADMQ/QKjs5ALViKo/w530-d-h253-p-rw/desk%2Bbackground.png") white no-repeat center top;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
overflow-x: none;
overflow-y:none; 
}
h2 {
Font-family: Arial;
top: 650px;
left: 500px;
position: absolute;
color: #525252;
font-size: 2vw;
letter-spacing: 1px;

}
h3 {
Font-family: Arial;
top: 900px;
left: 500px;
position: absolute;
color: #525252;
font-size: 2vw;
letter-spacing: 1px;

}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21%;
  left: 36%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 4.6vw;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  top: 720px;
  left: 310px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
color:#696969;
font-size: 17px;
 text-align: center;
line-height: 150%;
}

a {
color: white;
text-decoration:none;
}

ul li {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 43%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: normal;
  background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
ul li:link,
ul li:visited {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: normal;
  background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
ul li:hover,
ul li:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li a:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}  

ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
margin-right: 10%;
}  

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 0%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {

  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 40%;
  }

ul li{
   margin-left: 2px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   width: 100px;
   height:35px;
   top: 480%;
  }
ul{
margin-top: 165px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
  h1{
    position:absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 150px;
    font-size: 19px;
 }
h2 {

    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px; 
    left: 100px;
    top: 200px;
}

p {
    left: 30px;
    top: 390px;
}
hr {
margin-right: 85px;
margin-left: 85px;
margin-top: 375px;
}

}

hr {
margin-right: 150px;
margin-left: 150px;
margin-top: 570px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>WHO I AM</h1></center>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="life" ><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="prot"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="resume"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" class="me"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h2>Some Fun Facts</h2>
<p>
I made this website from scratch when I was 14, I have a twin brother whose <br> 
name is Pierson McNeal White, I have a older brother and sister who are also <br>
twins, I used to have 2 pet rats named Hermes and Cleo after the greek gods, <br>
and I watch the super bowl for the ads.
</p> 
<hr>
<h3>Me In A Nutshell</h3> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use media query to achieve your desired style for smaller devices:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   ul li {
      //whatever style
   }
}
```

So here, you are treating `li` elements differently when `screen` size is less than `768px`. You can change this number to whatever your consider as `phone` size